# Peut-on dire « un sous ensemble Y de A est dites algébrique s'il existe ... » ?

Tags: accord, mathématiques

Est-ce qu'on peut dire « un sous ensemble  Y de A **est dites** algébrique s'il existe … » ?

Si oui ou non, pourquoi ?

Comment: À moins qu'il y ait là une notion mathématique particulière que j'ignore (je ne suis pas de formation scientifique) c'est « dit » et pas « dites » parce que « dit » s'accorde avec sous-ensemble (tiret) qui est masculin singulier. Attends la confirmation, d'un plus matheux que moi. Bienvenue sur French.se.

Comment: Merci @Laure :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dire* s'accorde avec le sujet (*un sous-ensemble*) qui est masculin singulier. Il faut donc dire:

> Un [sous-ensemble](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sous-ensemble) Y de A est dit algébrique s'il existe (...)

Le mot *sous-ensemble* s'écrit avec un trait d'union. Autrement la construction de la phrase est correcte et me paraît tout à fait adaptée aux mathématiques. [Wikipédia donne, par exemple, la définition suivante](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_fini) pour un ensemble fini:

> Un ensemble E est dit fini si et seulement s'il existe un entier (...)

Comment: On peut ajouter que à l'oral on fera spontanément la liaison entre le "t" de *dit* et le "a" de algébrique et que donc le "t" s'entend [ditalʒe'bʁik].

Comment: Merci beaucoup Laurent G pour la confirmation et merci encore une fois @Laure pour l'éclairage, c'est très gentil.

Comment: @Laure, j'ai tendance à faire beaucoup de liaisons facultatives, mais ici c'est un contexte où je ne la ferais pas naturellement, au contraire ma lecture spontanée mais des poses plus longues que normale autour de « algébrique ».

Comment: Comme je n'avais entendu ça dire tout haut de ma vie j'ai essayé de le dire tout haut et j'ai fait la liaison et ça m'a paru bizarre sans liaison. Tu fais bien de rectifier et je vais peut-être enlever mon commentaire ?

Comment: @Laure, Ta remarque donne une raison probable pour laquelle l'OP a compris "dite", la garder offre un éclaircissement.  Simplement comme il s'agit ici d'une mention plutôt que d'un usage du mot "algébrique" -- on est en train d'en donner une définition (dans un texte soigné, il va se retrouver en italique et référencé dans l'index) -- la liaison ne me serait pas du tout spontanée.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: c'est justement ce que je m'étais dit, vu son apparemment déjà bon niveau de français j'avais pensé à un étudiant non francophone qui, venu étudier les maths en France, aurait entendu l'expression dans un de ses cours et chercherait à le retranscrire à l'écrit. J'aurais dû dire "on pourrait faire".

Answer (score 2):

Personnellement, la construction m’a toujours semblée étrange. Je préfère employer :

> Un **sous-ensemble algébrique** est un sous-ensemble Y de A qui […]
>
> On appelle **sous-ensemble algébrique** un sous-ensemble Y de A qui […]
>
> Un sous-ensemble Y de A est qualifié d’**algébrique** si […]
>
> On dit d’un sous-ensemble Y de A qu’il est **algébrique** si […]

Comment: Merci, Edouard pour les suggestions.